# How to add multiple foreign keys with nocheck for each one?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need to create multiple fk for diffrent fields with nocheck for each fk,

all the examples i see is only for 1 fk at a time,

i need something like this :

```
 ALTER TABLE contact  
WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_check5] 
           FOREIGN KEY (accountid) REFERENCES dbo.account ([accountid]),

WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_check6] 
           FOREIGN KEY (roleid) REFERENCES dbo.role ([id])
```

the disabled must be on the create level and not after it

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: the error i get is : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.

Comment: Why does it matter if you add them one after the other or in one go? Also, if you're using `NO CHECK`, that implies that you have rows where the value may not appear in the other table; meaning the foreign key can't be trusted. Is that hunch correct?

Comment: hey larnu for the first question , i need it because i am using t-sql from .net and want it on one command , for the second question yes i know it i need the fk only for erd diagram

Comment: You can pass multiple statements in a single command in .Net. What you can't do, however, is run multiple batches. It seems you're mixing up the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'NoCheck' will apply to all the constraints you add in the statement, you don't need to repeat it:

Example below (tested in SQL 2012):

```
CREATE TABLE account (accountid int, PRIMARY KEY (accountid))
GO

CREATE TABLE [role] (id int, PRIMARY KEY (id))
GO

CREATE TABLE contact (accountid int, roleid int)
GO

insert into contact values (1,1)
GO

ALTER TABLE contact
    WITH NOCHECK 
    ADD 
     CONSTRAINT [FK_check5] FOREIGN KEY (accountid) REFERENCES [account] ([accountid])
    ,CONSTRAINT [FK_check6]  FOREIGN KEY (roleid) REFERENCES [role] ([id])
```

---

If your intention is to only have the foreign key for ER diagramming, you can turn off enforcing of the constraint.  See the below article for more information.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/disable-foreign-key-constraints-with-insert-and-update-statements

as per the example provided in the article:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
ALTER TABLE Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader  
NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_PurchaseOrderHeader_Employee_EmployeeID;  
GO
```

That being said, I would recommend that you NEVER do this in a production system on an ongoing basis.  Foreign key constraints exist for a reason, to maintain data integrity.  If you are inserting data in a way that violates foreign key constraints you may want to review your data design.

Comment: i am also thought like your answer , but for some reason i am getting an error on create : The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_check5" , for some reason the nocheck not working for fk created this way.

Comment: I think you just said that you are getting the error when you attempt to insert a record after creating the constraint?  If that is the case then you are not understanding what the 'NoCheck' flag means.  NOCHECK just means that the constraint is not checked when it is created.  The constraint will be applied to any inserts or updates that you do after it is created

Comment: ok i understand , so what i am looking for is constraint that not checking the insert and updates at all after its created (created that constraint only for creating erd diagram from that database)

Comment: I have edited the answer with more information about how to disable enforcement of the constraint.

Answer (score 3):

seperate your alter table statement into two

```
ALTER TABLE contact  
WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_check5] 
           FOREIGN KEY (accountid) REFERENCES dbo.account ([accountid]);

ALTER TABLE CONTACTS
WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_check6] 
           FOREIGN KEY (roleid) REFERENCES dbo.role ([id]);
```